# Hibernate native sql join query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a problem with hibernate native sql join query. My query is below and works on Mysql db.

```
SELECT c.cart_id, u.name, u.surname, c.totalPrice
FROM sandbox.cart c JOIN
     sandbox.user u
     ON u.id = c.placedBy
```

I am using hibernate in code and encountered an exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1093)
```

Query in code here

```
Session session = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(ORDER_PER_USER_QUERY);
        query.addEntity(OrderPerUser.class);
        return query.list();
```

Table column name

Cart

> > | cart_id | placedBy | totalPrice

User

> > | id | email | name | surname

My mapped class is

```
   @Entity
public class OrderPerUser {
@Id
private long id;
private String name;
private String surName;
private long cartId;
private double totalPrice; }
```

Comment: I already added a mapped class. I added in question

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the line:
**query.addEntity(OrderPerUser.class);**
After that, you need to rewrite the code and map your object manually, because your **OrderPerUser** is not an entity:

```
Session session = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(ORDER_PER_USER_QUERY);
    List<OrderPerUser> returnList new ArrayList<>();
    for(Object[] row : query.list()){
        OrderPerUser orderPerUserObj = new OrderPerUser();
        oderPerUserObj.setCartId(Long.parseLong(row[0].toString()));
        //put other properties here
        returnList.add(orderPerUserObj);
    }
    return returnList;
```

**Edit1**: Now I see that you added the mapped class, but **OrderPerUser** should not be an **entity** in your case, but a regular **DTO**. An entity requires an ID, but you can't select the ID in this case, because OrderPerUser is not part of a table, it is just some selected data that you want in your memory and not in the database. So you should make your **OrderPerUser** a regular data transfer object.
Please read about entities, data transfer objects, data access objects to see what each object should do.

Comment: I use OrderPerUser class only mapping the list result. I want to return list only in memory. I dont want to persist db.

Comment: I don't persist anything in DB. What I do here, is return a list of the selected information. Nothing is persisted in DB and the returnList will hold the information that you selected and you can then put it in a cache if you want or do other things with it. I basically do exactly what you want to do.

Comment: And what error do you have now? The SQLException should not appear anymore because the root of that is that you are using **query.addEntity(OrderPerUser.class)**. Have you removed that line? Have you made the OrderPerUser not an entity, but a normal object?

Comment: No I didnt remove. Btw if I change column value in query like this   --> SELECT u.id, u.name, u.surname, c.cart_id, c.totalPrice. Exception change to  **Column 'cartId' not found.** Is it about mapping problem ?

Comment: You have to understand what ORM does and what ORM does not, before doing happy mappings all the way. In your case, entities are not a solution. You don't have a table represents a **OrderPerUser**. OrderPerUser is just in your application, a data transfer object, but not an entity. You need to stop mapping to ORM entities when it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `OrderPerUser` class which you try to use for collecting the result is expecting a column with name `id`, and you have no such column in your query...

Try using the query:

```
SELECT u.id, c.cart_id, u.name, u.surname, c.totalPrice
FROM sandbox.cart c 
     JOIN sandbox.user u ON u.id = c.placedBy
```